# Stop AJAX Calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, function

To load my page, I have to make several AJAX POSTS in a particular order and I achieved this by using the .done() function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Load Recipients & documents
    $("#page").hide();
    $("#loading").show();

    // Specify the loading order
    load_recipients().done(function(){
        load_documents().done(function() {
            $.when( initialize() ).then(function() {
                var deferreds = [];
                page_list.forEach(function(page_id, index) {
                    deferreds.push(load_fields(page_id));
                });

                $.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(function() {
                    $("#page").show();
                    $("#loading").hide();
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Now I am trying to implement error handling such that when an error is detected (by me or by HTTP error code) that the loading stops and an error message is displayed, however, I cannot figure out how to do that:

```
function load_recipients() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: base_url + "recipients/get/",
        type: "POST",
        data: { 
            packets_id : packets_id
        },
        success: function(response_data) {
            recipient_list = JSON.parse(response_data);
            if(recipient_list.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
                 // Make ALL functions stop and throw error message
            } else {
                console.log("Everything is fine");
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR){
            // Make ALL functions stop and throw error message
        }
    });
}
```

So far I've tried e.preventDefault(), .stop(), and stopPropogation() but none of them prevent the next AJAX POST from occurring. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can handle this?

Comment: None of the attempted methods mentioned have anything to do with ajax or promises

Comment: what is `initialize()`? Does it return a promise?

Comment: I will post the code above of initialize, it is not currently a promise--it is the basis for initializing jQuery UI Draggable & Drop settings. Will edit now.

Comment: Use async: https://github.com/caolan/async Look for control flow section

Comment: Don't need to full code of `initialize()` , it isn't relevant, just wanted to know if wrapping in `$.when` is appropriate or not. Seems like it should be called in final step

Comment: What about just taking the ajax call out of `$(document).ready(function(){...` and calling it explicitly when you want it, i.e. after the error check. Perhaps at the end of the ready function, something like `errorCheck = checkForErrors(); if (errorCheck){do ajax)}else{do something else}`

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own promise that you can resolve or reject yourself.

```
function load_recipients() {
    var promise = $.Deferred().promise();
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + "recipients/get/",
        type: "POST",
        data: { 
            packets_id : packets_id
        },
        success: function(response_data) {
            recipient_list = JSON.parse(response_data);
            if(recipient_list.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
                 promise.reject();
            } else {
                promise.resolve();
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR){
            promise.reject();
        }
    });
    return promise;
}
```

As for handling rejections I believe $.when().then handles this.

https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

```
deferred.then( doneFilter [, failFilter ] [, progressFilter ] )
```

> doneFilter Type: Function() A function that is called when the Deferred is resolved.
>
> failFilter Type: Function() An optional function that is called when the Deferred is rejected.

Comment: This is an ant-pattern .... `$.ajax` already returns a promise, there is no need to create a new one. Also doesn't answer question of where to catch rejections

Comment: Yes I proposed creating own promise because the promise ajax is returning is resolving even though he sent an error down from server. By creating own promise he can decide to reject or resolve it.

Comment: still doesn't answer the question

Comment: @charlietfl Well I apologize. Perhaps I don't understand the question. I thought he didn't know how to stop subsequent ajax calls. First thing I posted would stop them by having complete control over the rejection/resolution of the promise. I updated for handling catching rejections and resolutions as well. Am I still missing something? Thanks for the constructive criticism though! =]

Comment: I just wanted to thank you all for taking the time to look at this. I found a way to achieve the error handling I described above, although it is probably not the best way to do it. I will edit the question with my solution, but seriously, thank you so much for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best or most elegant way to accomplish what I was trying to do, but it is working. I moved the success check to the done function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Load Recipients & documents
    $("#page").hide();
    $("#loading").show();

    // Specify the loading order
    load_recipients().done(function(data){

        recipient_list = JSON.parse(data);
        if(recipient_list.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
            $("#alert-section .alert-danger").html("Please verify a recipient exists for this packet <a href='#'>Go Back</a>");
            $("#alert-section .alert-danger").removeClass("hidden");
            return false;   // Prevents next AJAX POST
        } else {
            console.log("It's all good in the hood");
        }

        load_documents().done(function() {
            $.when( initialize() ).then(function() {
                var deferreds = [];
                page_list.forEach(function(page_id, index) {
                    deferreds.push(load_fields(page_id));
                });

                $.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(function() {
                    $("#page").show();
                    $("#loading").hide();
                });
            });
        });
    });
});

function load_recipients() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: base_url + "recipients/get/",
        type: "POST",
        data: { 
            packets_id : packets_id
        },
        error: function(jqXHR){
            // When this error is hit, all subsequent AJAX POSTs are stopped automatically
            $("#alert-section .alert-danger").html("Please verify a recipient exists for this packet <a href='#'>Go Back</a>");
            $("#alert-section .alert-danger").removeClass("hidden");
        }
    });
}
```